# Probability : a hypothetical example.

Tags: probability

If someone performs 52 attempts of picking 1 card from a regular 52 card deck in order to find 1 specific card, he will get it 1 out of 52 times, true or false ? ( given the card shuffle is a perfectly random probability ).
or 
the probability restarts after every shuffle , and he may get it more or less than 1 time with every 52 attempts. 
:)

Comment: He could draw it any number of times between 0 and 52. There is a distribution for the *number* of times drawn. The average of this distribution is 1, which is the number of attempts (52) times the probability of drawing the card (1/52). But this average is not the only possible attained value.

Answer (score 1):

The probability restarts with every shuffle, that is correct. You can model this process with the geometric distribution. For that end, denote with $X$ the number of trials until the first success. Then $X$ is geometrically distributed with parameter $p=1/52$ and therefore *the expected number of trials* until you pick the specific card (success) is equal (as is known from the theory) to $$E[X]=\frac{1}{p}=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{52}}=52$$ This can be read as you have it in your second statement: *The expected number of trials until I pick the specific card is equal to 52.*

But with the geometric distribution you can do much more. You can calculate the probability of k trials until you hit it: $$P(X=k)=\left(1-\frac{1}{52}\right)^{k-1}\frac{1}{52^k}$$ for $k=1,2,\ldots$.

Answer (score 0):

The second statement is better. You define the probability of some event given a random experiment as $$\frac{\text{number of outputs of that random experiments that satisfy the event}}{\text{number of all possible outputs}}.$$

In your example the probability of picking 1 card from a 52 card deck is $1/52$. This doesn't mean that you **will** get that card after picking a card, replace the card, shuffling and picking again... 52 times. So more or less you will get the card every 52 attempts.